# OAuth1 implementation using requests library in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, oauth-1.0a

I'm trying implement OAuth1 using requests library in Python.

```
import random
import time
import string
import hmac
import base64
import hashlib
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote
​
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
url = "https://mdmenrollment.apple.com/session"
​
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
nonce_length = 16
nonce = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=nonce_length))
nonce = nonce + timestamp
​
nonce, timestamp, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret = map(quote, (nonce, timestamp, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret))
base_string = f"{consumer_key}&{nonce}&{timestamp}&{access_token}"
key = f"{consumer_secret}&{access_token_secret}"
signature = quote(base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key.encode('utf-8'), base_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha1).digest()).decode('utf-8'))
​
auth_header = f'OAuth oauth_nonce="{nonce}", oauth_timestamp="{timestamp}", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="{consumer_key}", oauth_token="{access_token}", oauth_signature="{signature}"'
print(auth_header)
​
request = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': auth_header})
print(request.text)
```

The request works if I use oauth2 or requests-oauthlib. The problem seems to be with signature or nonce but the response that I get back is just bad request so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Can someone tell me a better way to implement this using requests module.